# Can't use mouse in Edge, cant click anything

Tags: browser, mouse

After the latest update July 2017 in edge I cant click on anything when I use EDGE to browse just nothing works or is clickable. No problems at all in Firefox,,so must be Edge related.

Using windows 10 BTW.

Comment: Full antivirus scan and a full malware scan to start with. Try using IE rather than Edge too...

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well, and not just in Edge but also in the search bar of Windows 10. It would show up in search results, but they were not clickable.

After trying a bunch of things and reading other solutions, what worked for me was uninstalling the latest update for my graphics card driver. I have the Intel HD Graphics 4600.  I saw the same solution worked for others with different graphics card, so it's worth a try.

“Control Panel” → “uninstall a program” → search for the graphics card update (mine was back in June) → “uninstall” → restart the computer.